# How to check if a string has earlier been set using iabbr (full match)

Tags: vim

I am trying to check if a lhs is already abbreviated in vim.
mapcheck, however, seems to have a problem. For example,

```
iabbr swt switch
echo mapcheck('sw','i',1)
```

returns "switch" even when "switch" defined for "swt".
mapargs seem to return a string even if there is a partial
match with the lhs. Is there a way to find if an
abbreviation has been defined for the "exact" match, i.e.,
the above mapcheck returning a "" instead.

Update: I am trying to use mapcheck or maparg within a
function AddAbbr shown below

```
for [b:lhs, b:rhs_list] in items(b:english_words)
  call AddAbbr(b:lhs,b:rhs_list)
endfor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just put in:
`:verbose iabbr swt`
It should tell you what abbreviations there are for swt and where they're set. Yes, `:verbose iabbr sw` will also return this, but it shows you exactly what is abbreviated as what. Is this for a script or something?

If this is for a script, and you need a function rather than a command, then I'd use `maparg('swt','i',1)` -- I think that does what you want.